# How can I limit the amout of data locked in memory when using mmap?

Tags: mmap

In my application I mmap a very large file and access the locations randomly. However after a certain number of accesses the memory is completely used and the program starts to thrash.

I tried `madvise(fd, range, MADV_RANDOM)` and `madvise(fd, range, MADV_DONT_NEED)` for every access but this doesn't work. I also tried `setrlimit.RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` to limit the amount of memory locked in RAM.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. Are you reading or writing to the file? Are you really using a "real" file as backing of the mmap? If you are writing to the file, you are using `MAP_SHARED`, right?

Comment: I was doing something wrong. The memory overflow was due to sequential scan of a very mmaped large file and not due to random accesses to a file. Sorry for the confusion. My current solution is to mmap only a portion of the file at a time. I guess this is the recommended way of using mmap. I should mmap 500GB file in one shot.

Comment: Even on a 64 bits system, "unlimited" mmap isn't very good :-)

Comment: :). So I take there is no way to release the memory held by mmap?. What does madvise(MADV_RANDOM) and MADV_DONT_NEED do?.

Comment: You have to release mmap memory with `munmap` otherwise you'll exaust your virtual address space. The use of `MADV_RANDOM` is tied on how normally OS cache disk access. If you read 1kb of data, the OS often will read the next kb of data because he thinks you'll access the file sequentially. With the `MADV_RANDOM` option he won't do it. With a `MADV_DONT_NEED` the OS will free (technically will be free to free) all the pages he is keeping in memory as cache